# How to get the content of richedit control?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, bitmap, richedit

I have a RichEdit ctrl, that was filled by mixed plain text and bitmap data, the bitmap data was inserted by the method [described here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/richedit/article.php/c5383/Insert-any-HBITMAP-Bitmap-in-your-RichEdit-Control.htm). How can i get the content of the RichEdit?
I want to know where(the begin position) the BITMAP data was inserted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [IRichEditOle::GetObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.  The `cp` field of the returned [`REOBJECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct tells you an object's character position in the RichEdit.